# Getting error while deploying external services for Sitecore 10 on Azure Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run vanilla `Sitecore 10.2` on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). Getting error when deploying external services (`mssql`, `solr`)

```
kubectl apply -f .\external\
```

- In PowerShell, I can see success message

[image]

- and in Azure, I can see services are running fine:

[image]

- But some issues with the deployments and pods :

[image]
[image]

Because of this error, jobs are also not created. Any help is much appreciated.